# download code(readfile) gives me a empty or corrupt file

Tags: php, file

i'm trying to build a download page which gets the file id and the generates download link by getting files information from database

it kinda works ! for some reason i get a file from this page but it's not really a file ! 
for example when i send a picture id to this page a picture will be downloaded but it wont open and it's size is really smaller than what really is

here is my code

```
  <?php
require_once('class/comon.php');
require_once('class/db.php');

    $file_id = isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id'] != 0 ? (int)$_GET['id'] : exit;
    $file = comon::get_fileinfo('files' , 'id' , $file_id );
    if(!$file) exit;

    foreach($file as $file){
    $location = $file['location'];
    $filename = $file['file_name'];
    }

    $ext = end(explode('.' , $filename ));

header( 'Pragma: public' ); 
header( 'Expires: 0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: private', false ); 
header( 'Content-Type: application/'.$ext);
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. basename($filename) . '";' );
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( 'http://localhost/Lancer/attach/'.$location.'/'.$filename ) );
readfile( 'http://localhost/Lancer/attach/'.$location.'/'.$filename );


?>
```

i've printed file path on the page

```
echo 'localhost/Lancer/attach/'.$location.'/'.$filename;
```

and then i put the output on the url and it shows the picture so that cant be the problem

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want either `readfile('http://localhost/....')` or the absolute local file path to the file.

To use the URL string you need to provide a protocol to readfile.

Comment: thanx i've add the 'http://' before localhost and now i get a empty  file with 0 size! still when i printout the path and put the output on url it shows the picure

Comment: @max, you need to also correct the path in the `filesize()` call when sending the Content-Length header.

Comment: thanx actually i findout that i should use only relative path for filesize to work , it's working now but fore some reason it doesn't show pictures , it adds some weird characters to the text file , zip files are ok though !